# Binding property to Silverlight dependency property independent of DataContext

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-binding

I'm trying to make an `Address` control that has an `IsReadOnly` property, which will make every `TextBox` inside read only when set to true.

```
 <my:AddressControl Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

I've managed to do this just fine with a dependency property and it works.

Here's a simple class with the dependency property declared :

```
public partial class AddressControl : UserControl
{
    public AddressControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReadOnlyProperty = 
       DependencyProperty.Register("IsReadOnly", typeof(bool), 
                                   typeof(AddressControl), null);

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

In the XAML for this codebehind file I have a `Textbox` for each address line:

```
  <TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Text="{Binding City, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
  <TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Text="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
  <TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}" Text="{Binding Zip, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Like i said this works just fine.
The problem is that the `Address` control itself is bound to its parent object (I have several addresses I am binding).

```
 <my:AddressControl DataContext="{Binding ShippingAddress, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True">
 <my:AddressControl DataContext="{Binding BillingAddress, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True">
```

The problem is that as soon as I set `DataContext` to something other than `'this'` then the binding for `IsReadOnly` breaks. Not surprising because its looking for `IsReadOnly` on the `Address` data entity and it doesn't exist or belong there.

I've tried just about every combination of [binding attributes](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf) to get `IsReadOnly` to bind to the  `AddressControl` obejct but can't get it working.

I've tried things like this, but I can't get `IsReadOnly` to bind independently to the `AddressControl` property instead of its `DataContext`.

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsReadOnlyProperty}" Text="{Binding City, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I think I'm pretty close. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Having played with the binding tool for the 'Text' property it seems that 'RelativeSource Self' actually means bind to the TextBox itself - which isn't what I want. Therefore I think I need FindAncestor  which doesn't exist in Silverlight yet :-( I think i am stuck? http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=480603

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[With this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421581/silverlight-binding-a-child-controls-property-to-a-property-in-a-user-control/2528018#2528018) (actually my own answer to a similar question) I have a good [better] solution.

I still have to iterate through the textboxes, but I don't have to set the actual value. I can create bindings in the codebehind - just not with XAML.

Comment: Just like to say this is the right approach, and the flagged answer is wrong - it IS possible and you're not stuck.

Comment: oh ya and I just realized this was my question so I can change the answer. lol

Comment: what I think ken means is you can't do this just with XAML Bindings - but fortunately its possible to create a binding in code

Answer (score 0):

I think you're stuck, at least, if you want to do this just via binding.  My guess is that you're going to have to resort to code-behind, presumably by iterating through your child textbox controls and setting their IsReadOnly propert as a side-effect of your Address control's IsReadOnly property.

Unlike some folks who think that any code sitting in a code-behind file is effectively an admission of failure, I don't get religious about it: if throwing some code into a code-behind is the easiest way to do something, that's where I put my code.  On the contrary, if I have to spend half a day trying to figure out how to do something via binding that I could do in five minutes with a code-behind, *that's* failure, IMO.

Comment: if im stuck i'm find - just didnt want to miss something. these kind of learning experiences help you understand the framework a lot better even if you definitely do waste some time initially. definitely agree on the code-behind side of things - see my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489415/how-to-get-a-codebehind-file-for-an-asp-net-mvc-view-in-rc1-to-be-created-by-de