# Binding Silverlight UserControl to a complex object

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, user-controls

What is the "best" (or the most-often-used) approach when binding a complex class to a user control for re-use?

I am trying to create some reusable libraries for classes, and I am not sure which approach I should use. Example: I want to create an Address library that defines and Address class (with properties Line1, Line2 etc.), it's validation logic and an AddressControl which acts as the viewer/editor with bound fields for each property.

In use I might have a customer class with BillingAddress, DeliveryAddress properties and I would want to bind these in my customer control thus:

```
<addressLib:AddressControl [xxx]="{Binding BillingAddress}" />
```

So the question is what do I put in XXX?

Initially I thought of creating a DependencyProperty 'Address' on the control:

```
<addressLib:AddressControl Address="{Binding BillingAddress}" />
```

But now I am thinking surely I could just use the existing DataContext property?

```
<addressLib:AddressControl DataContext="{Binding BillingAddress}" />
```

Is this the best approach? Are there any issues e.g. updates or NotifyPropertyChange issues?

many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference to remember is that with dependency property you get change notification and with datacontext you don't (at least not untill SL5 is out)

Comment: Thanks for warning - I think I could possibly raise an event from the control to indicate the change.

Comment: I've change this to be the correct answer, as using the DataContext is not reliable as you don't get the change notification. While it's not wrong it makes the control a One-Time binding and it won't update if the parent control changes the datacontext. That's a fairly limited use case IMHO, so the dependency property approach is the right one.

Comment: If anyone is interested this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421581/silverlight-binding-a-child-controls-property-to-a-property-in-a-user-control/2528018#2528018 demonstrates the best approach to binding values in controls.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the DataContext of your control to your model (in this case a BillingAddress) is the way to go. If your Control is used in a DataTemplate for an ItemsControl then the DataContext would be of course just "{Binding}".