# How to set WPF border.Brush to foreground property of other controls like labels?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

How to set WPF border.Brush to foreground property of other controls like labels?

```
Border b = new Border();
b.BorderBrush= ?;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just bind it in XAML as such:

```
 <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Path=Foreground, ElementName=txtLabel}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this similar question

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/421581/silverlight-binding-a-child-controls-property-to-a-property-in-a-user-control

If this doesn't help, why not define a static resource for your foreground colour:

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundColour" Color="#FFF2F2F2" />
```

Then bind this foreground colour to any control that you like.

Through code it would be something like :

```
  fg = this.Resources["ForegroundColour"] as SolidColorBrush;
        b.BorderBrush= fg;
```